# Buscar parte de uma string dentro de um vetor

Tags: java

Bem tenho um vetor que recebe varias linhas texto. Porém eu preciso comparar essas linhas e ver se encontro uma palavra, tentei com o equals() mas ele só retorna verdadeiro se encontrar exatamente a mesma string e o contains() não funciona com o vetor. ex:

Palavra que eu quero buscar: **tomate**

texto do vetor:

[0] = Alfaces são verdes.

[1] = Os **tomate**s são vermelhos.

[2] = Pimentões são coloridos.

Deixei o código assim. Ele me retorna a linha em que se encontra a palavra buscada o que já serve para meus objetivos.

```
public int buscaLinha(String[] vetor, String palavra)
{
   int i = 1;
   for(String p : vetor)
   {
       if(p.contains(palavra)) {
           return i;
       }
       i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de agradecer desde já pela atenção a mim oferecida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar com o seguinte código:

```
public boolean encontrarPalavra(String[] vetor, String palavra)
{
   for(String p : vetor)
   {
       if(p.contains(palavra))
         return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de código em PHP

```
public function buscarPalavra ($palavraBuscada, $array)
{
   if(in_array($palavraBuscada,$array)){
      echo "Palavra encontrada: $palavraBuscada";
   }else{
      echo "Palavra Não Localizada!";
   }
}
```

Comment: Olá Christian, [bem-vindo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ao Stackoverflow em Português. Acredito que ele queira a resposta em `Java`, pois foi utilizada esta *tag* na pergunta.

Comment: Vlw cara em php eu ja conhecia, mas obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se JAVA contém o método Substring, mas se tiver talvez seja uma opção. Desenvolvi isto em C# e funcionou, como C# é relativamente semelhante a JAVA, coloco aqui este método para tentar ajudar também. Este método é semelhante ao colocado pelo Murilo Fechio:

```
public static bool existe_no_vetor (string[] aux, string strpretendida)
{
    foreach (string str in aux)
        {
            if (str.Contains(strpretendida) == true)
                return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, provavelmente vou usar quando voltar a programar em C#